# Spring MVC data binding diff in javabean and @RequestParam boolean request parameter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, annotations, boolean

Spring MVC support request parameter to javabean. But when I want to bind **boolean**,
It is still not work in javabean.

If the code in controller is:

```
public void test(@RequestParam(value="isCheck") boolean isCheck)
```

I can get the **isCheck** boolean value.

But when the code in contoller is:

```
public void test(TestVO testVO)
```

TestVO javabean:

```
public class TestVO {

private boolean isPrecheck;

public boolean isPrecheck() {
    return isPrecheck;
}

public void setPrecheck(boolean isPrecheck) {
    this.isPrecheck = isPrecheck;
}
}
```

I can not set the request parameter to this Javabean.

Anyone has ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you the PropertiesEditor of the Spring.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomBooleanEditor.html

Inside your controller create a method to set the editor

```
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

      binder.registerCustomEditor(Boolean.class, new CustomBooleanEditor(allowEmpty???));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to boolean naming convention and associated ambiguity with its getter methods.
Rename your boolean from **isPrecheck** to **precheck** and it will work.